# Drools decision table - function call for condition param, so that the condition will be evaluated by comparing the values coming from the function

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

In my drools decision table, I want to keep a getter or function call in the condition cell, so that the condition will be evaluated over the value coming from that getter or function.
i.e for the $param, I want the cell to evaluate param value from the getter call. and then evaluate the condition.

I kept a condition as $analytics.getProp1() <= ($param)
Now for this param, I want the condition cell to get the value from a function (getter call) like this
$analytics.getProp2(). So that the actual evaluation will be $analytics.getProp1() <= $analytics.getProp2()

[image]

In the attached example, I'm trying to get the value from getProp2() and to use in for the param.
What should be the correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by passing value in 1 condition cell for each row, as I needed to evaluate the condition as OR and not as AND.
The issue was resolved yesterday and I forgot to post answer. Thanks for your response
In the above scenario, I kept the value for both the condition in rows, however only 1 of my condition can be true at once, So I neeeded to keep the other condition value cell empty. Below is the solution image for the same.

[image]

My conditions were as if first condition is true, the other condition will be false. Since I was keeping values for both the conditions (where 1 condition was getting true while the second was false) making the rule false.

Answer (score 1):

Drools will interpret an expression in the rows used to generate the rules.

```
| DESCRIPTION | CONDITION                 | ACTION                      |
|             | $analytics: MyAnalytics()                               |
|             | prop1 <= $1               | $analytics.setSomething($1) |
|-------------|---------------------------|-----------------------------|
| Example1    | 5                         | 500                         |
| Example2    | $analytics.getProp2()     | $analytics.getProp1()       |
```

I think, but I don't have a Drools interpreter on hand to confirm, that you don't even need to explicitly include the `$analytics` bit in the rule generating row. That's because we're effectively generating a rule with the DRL condition of `$analytics: MyAnalytics( prop1 <= prop2 )` which doesn't require any reference to the parent object:

```
| DESCRIPTION | CONDITION                 | ACTION                      |
|             |             $analytics: MyAnalytics()                   |
|             | prop1 <= $1               | $analytics.setSomething($1) |
|-------------|---------------------------|-----------------------------|
| Example3    | prop2                     | 500                         |
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the concern. I was able to resolve the issue. have posted the answer below.